# Error while dropping row from dataframe based on value comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I have following unique values in dataframe column.

```
['1473' '1093' '1346' '1324' 'NA' '1129' '58' '847' '54' '831' '816']
```

I want to drop rows which have `'NA'` in this column.

```
testData = testData[testData.BsmtUnfSF != "NA"]
```

and got error

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Then I tried

```
testData = testData[testData.BsmtUnfSF != np.NAN]
```

It doesn't give any error but it doesn't drop rows.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: would you like show us the dataframe head  >

Comment: How about ‘pandas.DataFrame.dropna’?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it. Just change `column` with the column name you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"column": [1,2,3,np.nan,6]})
df = df[np.isfinite(df['column'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

```
testData = testData.dropna(subsets = 'BsmtUnfSF']
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming your dataFrame:

```
>>> df
    col1
0   1473
1   1093
2   1346
3   1324
4    NaN
5   1129
6     58
7    847
8     54
9    831
10   816
```

## You have multiple solutions:

```
>>> df[pd.notnull(df['col1'])]
    col1
0   1473
1   1093
2   1346
3   1324
5   1129
6     58
7    847
8     54
9    831
10   816

>>> df[df.col1.notnull()]
#  df[df['col1'].notnull()]
    col1
0   1473
1   1093
2   1346
3   1324
5   1129
6     58
7    847
8     54
9    831
10   816


>>> df.dropna(subset=['col1'])
    col1
0   1473
1   1093
2   1346
3   1324
5   1129
6     58
7    847
8     54
9    831
10   816

>>> df.dropna()
    col1
0   1473
1   1093
2   1346
3   1324
5   1129
6     58
7    847
8     54
9    831
10   816

>>> df[~df.col1.isnull()]
    col1
0   1473
1   1093
2   1346
3   1324
5   1129
6     58
7    847
8     54
9    831
10   816
```